# How do I install acts_as_ferret in Windows XP?

Tags: rubygems, acts-as-ferret

I cannot install [Acts As Ferret](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/acts_as_ferret) in Windows XP. My development environment is,

- [RubyGems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RubyGems) - 1.7.2
- Ruby -  1.8.7
- devkit - 4.5.1

When I ran the command `gem install acts_as_ferret`, I got the error below. Any clue?

```
C:\TEMP\test\devkit>gem install acts_as_ferret

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing acts_as_ferret:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/Ruby187/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
gcc -I. -I/C/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mingw32 -I/C/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mingw32 -  I.   -g -O2 -DFD_SETSIZE=256   -W
all -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500  -c fs_store.c
fs_store.c: In function 'fs_store_new':
fs_store.c:431:17: warning: unused variable 'stt'
gcc -I. -I/C/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mingw32 -I/C/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mingw32 -  I.   -g -O2 -DFD_SETSIZE=256   -W
all -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500  -c global.c
global.c: In function 'signal_to_string':
global.c:412:14: error: 'SIGBUS' undeclared (first use in this function)
global.c:412:14: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function   it appears in
global.c: In function 'frt_init':
global.c:436:22: error: storage size of 'action' isn't known
global.c:443:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'sigemptyset'
global.c:446:5: error: storage size of '__old' isn't known
global.c:446:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'sigaction'
global.c:446:5: warning: unused variable '__old'
global.c:447:5: error: storage size of '__old' isn't known
global.c:447:5: warning: unused variable '__old'
global.c:448:5: error: storage size of '__old' isn't known
global.c:448:5: warning: unused variable '__old'
global.c:449:5: error: storage size of '__old' isn't known
global.c:449:5: error: 'SIGBUS' undeclared (first use in this function)
global.c:449:5: warning: unused variable '__old'
global.c:450:5: error: storage size of '__old' isn't known
global.c:450:5: warning: unused variable '__old'
global.c:436:22: warning: unused variable 'action'
make: *** [global.o] Error 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/jk-ferret-0.11.8.3   for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/jk-ferret-0.11.8.3/ext/gem_make.out
```

Comment: It appears that you don't have the latest ruby installed.  The current version is 1.9.2.  You can run `ruby update --system` and then reinstall acts_as_ferret

Comment: I got the same problem with ruby 1.9.2. So I went back to the 1.8.7. But the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

From my research acts_as_ferret is buggy.  It has problems installing, running and corrupts indexes.  You should consider moving to [Sphinx](http://kpumuk.info/projects/ror-plugins/sphinx/%22Sphinx%22)

Comment: sigh! my original env is linux and my project uses acts_as_ferret all over the code. Right I want to move to windows XP design env and I ran into the problem. I donot know what it is going on.

Comment: This might come off as a little rude, but if you did some research before using the gem you might have found that it is buggy...

Comment: that is all right. I just inherited the project from someone else. Do u think sdskes_acts_as_ferret could be a good replacement?

Comment: I don't think anything with acts_as_ferret will be a good replacement; I'm assuming it's all buggy.